# Select SUM "separately" for the past 30 days

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a MySQL table which is as follows

```
------------------------------------------------
|  id       | user_id | day    | value         |
|  INT(11)  | INT(11) | INT(8) | DECIMAL(5,2)  |
------------------------------------------------
```

Day is (Ymd) number like this: 20191012

I want to grab the `SUM(value)` for Today and the past 29 days `separately` (30 days, based on day column)

I thought of a loop like this

```
for($i=0;$i<=30;$i++)
{
    $query = "SELECT SUM(value) FROM table WHERE day=".date('Ymd', strtotime("-{$i} days"));
}
```

But how can I achieve this more efficiently?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is there data in the table for all days?

Comment: @Nick Not always, no. I just need to show whatever exists.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @Nick 5.7.27 , but I can upgrade to 8 if it makes things simpler.

Comment: @J.Doe Could you share some rows and expected result? You can use https://www.db-fiddle.com/ for demonstration.

Comment: @vivek_23 Thanks for mentioning db-fiddle to me, I didn't know about it until now, but for the situation `Evil_skunk`'s answer works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Group By](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) to fetch it with a single MySQL-Query

```
SELECT day, SUM(value) FROM table GROUP BY day WHERE day >= ".date('Ymd', strtotime("-29 days"));
```

It should work because your `day` field is a number and will increase everyday so you can just compare it with gte

Expected output will be

```
---------------------------
|  day      | SUM(value)  |
|  INT(8)   |             |
---------------------------
|  20191012 |    15.25    |
---------------------------
|  20191011 |    29.13    |
---------------------------
|    ...    |      ...    |
---------------------------
```

J4I: If there are days without values in your dataset, the missing "day-row" is also missing in the output so it could be that there are less than 30 result-rows.

Comment: I just had to edit it to: `"SELECT day, SUM(value) AS sum FROM table WHERE day > ".date('Ymd', strtotime("-29 days"))." GROUP BY day";` and now it works perfectly, simple and elegant, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This query will work for any version of MySQL. It creates a temporary numbers table with the numbers from 0-29, then uses that to compute a list of days from today to 29 days earlier. This is then `LEFT JOIN`ed to the data table to compute the sum per day, with 0 sums where there is no data for a given day:

```
SELECT  d.day, COALESCE(SUM(value), 0)
FROM (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() -INTERVAL n10.n * 10 + n.n DAY, '%Y%m%d') AS day
      FROM (SELECT 0 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 
            UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 
            UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) n
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2) n10) d
LEFT JOIN `table` t ON t.day = d.day
GROUP BY d.day
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=599c378d9552c1a0e363d05e9e5e0c28)

Comment: Thank you very much for putting your valuable time into this Mr. Nick, but this is too complex for my limited MySQL knowledge, so I thought it's better if I go with Evil_Skunk's answer above, which I understand and can edit later. Thanks again.

Comment: @J.Doe no problem at all. I've updated the demo with a couple of intermediate results should you be interested in getting a bit more insight into how it works at some future point. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ffc8f0c2bec94115cb884a8f8d89bf99